# How to access virtual documents in Firestore through Firebase SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner and my firestore database has a collection which has documents and each document has a subcollection without any other fields. I can't find a way to access the ID of the empty document and get the subcollection associated with the doc using the SDK. I could do it on console but I have to too much to do and cannot also make changes to my application for now so I need to use the SDK. Please suggest me some way to access them like the console.

Comment: Can you show an image of your Firestore database/console and point exactly which docs and collections you are speaking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I used collection group query(`collectionGroup`) to query the documents in the subcollections(which have the same `id`s) and found the IDs of the parent document by the `parent` property.
Huge thanks to @mark carlton and @Renaud Tarnec for these suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how the `CollectionReference` of the sub-collection, you can easily get the parent `DocumentReference` with [`parent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent) property of the `CollectionReference`. From the `DocumentReference` you just need to use the [`id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#id) property.

You didn't share much details on your data model, so it is difficult to give more guidance on how to find the `CollectionReference`. Mark's answer presents some possible approaches.

Answer (score 0):

CASE 1: If the subcollections are queried across multiple documents, you could use a collection group query which queries collections of the same name regardless of their position in the hierarchy. This way you don't actually need to know the ID of the document
CASE 2: Use a document ID you will remember for such a case as opposed to having a UID for the ID. This was your queries make much more sense to you